# Show that a set is connected and contractible?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I am having trouble with a practice qual exam question:

Let $X = \{x,y\}$ with $\emptyset,X,\{x\}$ open.  Show that X is connected and contractible?

For the first part, I would assume not. That there is a separation of $X = A \cup B$.  This would imply that $x\in A$ and $y \in B$.  However since the singleton $\{y\}$ is not open, this results in a contradiction? Hence X is connected.

As for showing that X is contractible, I am kinda stuck?  Any help?

Comment: How about constructing a homotopy of the whole space to a point?

Comment: You could also say that the only non-empty set that is both open and closed is $X$. This implies connectedness.

Comment: Note that the only neighborhood of $y$ is $X$, so there can be no disconnection (every neighborhood of $x$ must also meet every neighborhood of $y$).

Answer (score 2):

It's a good question.

I construct a continuous map : $ H = \begin{cases} \text {  identity map  } , &t \in [0,1/2] \\ x \text {   (constant   map)   } , &t\in (1/2,1] \end{cases} $

Then,I find $ H^{-1}(\{x\}) = (\{x\} \times [0,1])\cup (\{x,y\} \times (1/2,1]) $ is a open set, so is $H^{-1}(\{x,y\})$.

Hence, $H $ is continuous, $H(*,0)$ = identity map, and $H(*,1) $= constant map.

Does it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, there are finitely-many functions between the spaces $X$ and, say $Y$:={$x$} (where {$x$} is given the only possible topology on 1 element, the indiscrete topology).

So we need to find functions $f: X \rightarrow$ {$ x $} and $g: Y \rightarrow X$ so that

i) $g \circ f \simeq Id_Y$ and

ii) $f \circ g \simeq Id_X $

There are very few actual possible functions to test for, e.g., the  function from $Y$:={$ x$} to $X$  is the inclusion map . We use this function as our only possible $g$. And we use in the opposite direction , for f, the constant function $f:==x$.

We then have ,

$g \circ f= x$ , where x is the constant function. Now, $g \circ f=x=Id_X$ ,since any function is homotopic to itself (use $H(x,t)=Id_X$ for all t).

Now we check $f \circ g: X \rightarrow X$ . Again, this function takes $x$ to itself, so it is  to the constant function $x$ on $X$. I would think that the homotopy $ H: X \times I \rightarrow X$ that works
is $H(x,t)=x  \forall t ; H(y,0)=y , H(y,t)=x ;0<t\leq 1 $. But we need to show this map is continuous for all pairs $(x,t)$ (using the product topology on $ X \times I$). But $H^{-1}$ {$ x$}=$x \times I$ , which is open in $X \times I$ for t in $(0,1]$. And $H^{-1}$ ({$ x$})=$\emptyset$ for $t=0$.

There are i's to dot and some t's to cross, but I think this does it.